# Which synchronization guarantees does c++ provide for cache lines?

Tags: c++, multithreading, caching, c++17

In a recent discussion with a colleague, the following problem came up without us reaching a conclusion: If 1 thread is constantly reading a certain cache line, does that cache line (in the processor) get guaranteed updated, when the synchronization is on a different level than that data.

I've tried to simulate this in a small piece of code in order to illustrate:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

constexpr static auto CACHE_LINE_SIZE = 64;
constexpr static auto NOF_CHARS = CACHE_LINE_SIZE / sizeof(char);
constexpr static auto DELAY = std::chrono::milliseconds{1};

alignas(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) char text[CACHE_LINE_SIZE / sizeof(char)];

int main() {
  auto whichToRead = std::atomic<int>{0};
  auto running = std::atomic<bool>(true);
  text[0] = '0';
  auto t = std::thread{[&whichToRead, &running]() {
    while (running) {
      std::cout << text[whichToRead] << std::endl;
    }
  }};

  for (auto i = 1; i < NOF_CHARS; ++i) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(DELAY);
    for (auto j = 0; j <= i; ++j) text[j] = '0' + j;
    ++whichToRead;
  }
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(DELAY);
  running = false;
  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

[The code at compiler-explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/eEM4ozqjj)

As you see in the code, `text` is some piece of memory that is aligned on a cache line and is exactly 1 cache line in size.

The thread `t` is a thread that constantly reads the value and does something with it (for example sake, this prints it to the console).

The main thread updates the memory in that cache line (even overriding the existing data with the same content) and then via some synchronization independent from the cache line (in the example, a `std::atomic`, in real life a `std::mutex` in completely unrelated code) after which the reading thread `t` needs to process the new stuff.

Although this works in this example and we see the printed value is updated, the question is: Is this guaranteed by the c++ standard to correctly work independently from the processor used?

For answers:

- Preferably with quotes from the standard
- You can assume this code is compiled with c++17, if this somehow got fixed in c++20 or c++23 that's also useful to know.

**Update:** `for (auto j = 0; j <= i; ++j) text[j] = '0' + j;` causes a race condition, do we still have problems if that gets replaced by `text[i] = '0' + j;`

Comment: The standard says that this code is UB.  You are not allowed to use a memory location in two or more threads if one of those threads is a writer and you do not have synchronization.  Doing so is a [data race and is UB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67739347/can-i-safely-pass-nullptr-to-pure-c-libraries-functions)

Comment: OT: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.

Comment: @NathanOliver Isn't using that atomic sufficient as synchronization?

Comment: @JVApen `text` elements are not atomic.

Comment: Not here.  There is no guard that stops `std::cout << text[whichToRead] << std::endl;` and `text[j] = '0' + j;` from accessing the same element of the array at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. If it would just be writing all bytes which are different, basically: `text[i] = '0' + i;` would that be a problem?

Comment: That should be safe since the thread wouldn't be reading the element that main is writing to.  Unfortunately that will put you into a [false sharing](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads.html) scenario which will make the code run as if you are doing this without threads.

Comment: Also, `CACHE_LINE_SIZE / sizeof(char)` can just be `CACHE_LINE_SIZE` in your code.  `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` on all conforming implementations.

Comment: @NathanOliver If I understood false sharing correctly, this is that the cache does get cleared because of the write. So that implies that this code will be working, and you pay a performance penalty in the case that the cache line gets written.

Comment: Yes, When you write, the cache line is invalidated.  Once the reader goes to read, it sees that, stops to reload the cache line, and the does it read.  The code will work correctly, but it wont be as fast as it could be.  If the different elements are in different cache lines, then you would get the full performance.

Comment: In this specific case, that ain't something I solve. Your link about the false sharing was about intel CPUs. If I'm correct, those are the most forgiving if it comes to multi-threading. Does the same guarantee hold for ARM, SPARK ... ?

Comment: @JVApen I believe this affects any processor that uses a shared cache.  I only deals with x86-64 so I can't tell you for sure if ARM and others have the same issue.